# Created upstart job that works - system doesn't boot to CLI but everything works SSH,RDP etc

Tags: boot, upstart

The thing is I happen to have a monitor near me where I can watch my server boot and at boot it never makes it to the login prompt. It is just staying at right after it runs my Upstart Job.

```
VRDE server is listening on port 9000
* Start CUPS     [OK]
* Start Samba    [OK]
* Stopping Samba [OK]
```

Here is the script and how I made it

```
# Start VirtualBox @boot 
# Script = /etc/init.d/StartVM

#Edit these variables!
VMUSER=user
VMNAME=vmname

start on filesystem and static-network-up
stop on runlevel [016]

sudo -u $VMUSER VBoxHeadless --startvm $VMNAME
```

I created it via:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/StartVM

sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/StartVM

sudo update-rc.d StartVM defaults 99 01
```

Comment: I should mention that the script also causes my reboot command to fail, but thats kinda  a seperate thread, tho I am sure its related, I got the idea, but It needs some fine tuning, I think the problem lies in the command at the end of the script and perhaps the start/stop and or defaults # #

Answer (score 0):

Changed the last line to >>

```
sudo -u $VMUSER VBoxHeadless --startvm $VMNAME &
```